# Excel VBA Click Cell to Fire Macro - Not working with Merged Cells

Tags: excel, vba

I am using the code below to fire a macro on the click of a cell. The cell in question is a header "Mitch's Macro" but it on merged cells B5 through J5. I have tried naming this merged range to MITCH, but it still doesnt run on click... Any ideas? Thank you in advance!

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Selection.Count = 1 Then
        If Not Intersect(Target, Range("MITCH")) Is Nothing Then
            MsgBox ("Hello World")
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: When you select a merged cell you're selecting all the cells in the merge range - so your code skips the `INTERSECT` part due to `Selection.Count=1`.

Comment: Hi Darren! Thank you so much. By setting it to Selection.Count = 9 (the number of cells merged) I was able to fix the issue! I appreciate your help!

Comment: You could just remove the `Selection.Count` bit and rely on the `Intersect` line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is Selection.Count = 1.
The merged cells have more than one cells so once you select any cell in the merged area, the code doesn't get executed.

Please give this a try...

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("MITCH")) Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox ("Hello World")
    End If
End Sub
```

**Edit:**

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim rng As Range
    Set rng = Range("MITCH")
    If Target.CountLarge > rng.Cells.Count Then Exit Sub
    If Not Intersect(Target, rng) Is Nothing And Target.Cells(1).Address = rng.Cells(1).Address Then
        MsgBox ("Hello World")
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Sktneer, that works really great as well! Now I dont have to set the number of merged cells. Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: @mitchmitch24 You're welcome! Glad your issue is resolved. :)

Comment: Just to note, this will run the code as expected, when Range("Mitch") is clicked, but also when any selection including that range is made (try `ctrl+a`) - which may not be the desired behaviour. In that case `If Target.Address = Range("MITCH").Address Then ...` may be preferred?

Comment: Hi Greedo- I see what you mean... Hmm. I tried adjusting the code using the target.address and range.address, but it doesnt seem to work in my existing code. Any further help with this would be appreciated! (The people using this wont probably be doing crtl+A but I'd like to make it as smooth as possible, just in case!) Thank you!

Comment: You should be able to just replace the whole `IF INTERSECT(.....` line with the code that @Greedo supplied in his comment.

Comment: I tried `Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)

        If Target.Address = Range("MITCH").Address Then

            MsgBox ("Hello World")

        End If
    
End Sub` ... but it no longer msgbox upon clicking the cell.

Comment: Your latest tweaked code should work without an issue.

Comment: That's weird - just copied the code from your comment and pasted into an Excel worksheet.  Created the merged cell, named it and everything worked fine.

Comment: @mitchmitch24 Ah, sorry, that should've been `Target(1,1).Address` -
 `Target` returns the entire selected range whereas `Range("MITCH")` only returns the TL cell, so Target **(1,1)** grabs the top left of the selection _(or indeed `Target.Cells(1,1).Address` if you want to use the longhand)_

Comment: Also are you sure that you are not disabling the event anywhere in the code? If so, open immediate window by pressing Ctrl+G and type there ?Application.EnableEvents and see what you get? A true or false. If you get false, type Application.EnableEvents = True and your code should work fine then.

Comment: @mitchmitch24 See the edited answer. I hope that takes care of all your issues.

Comment: Sktneer, I get true. I'll do some reading on that. I am still a beginner-ish with VBA, and I didnt know you could check it like that! And Greedo, thank you! Adding the Target.Cells(1,1).Address got it perfectly. I am in Excel 2010, so Im not sure if I have to use the longhand, the shorthand didnt quite catch it. I appreciate all of your guys help!

Comment: @mitchmitch24 Not quite perfect actually, as *any* selection with the same top left cell as your named range will return positively. I've added another answer to this end in order to keep the comments clean. @sktneer, your code doesn't seem to work for me - specifically I have `B2:D3` merged and named, and `rng.Cells.Count` returns 1 when I select this, while `Target.CountLarge` returns 6, so the macro quits. Perhaps checking `rng`s `MergeArea` would do the trick (see my answer)?

Comment: It works perfectly fine for me considering your setup as well. If I merge the cells B2:D3, the rng.cells.count returns 6 for me. Not sure why it returns 1 for you though.

Answer (score 2):

After a little more thinking I realised that most answers have a few drawbacks, and I think this is what we're really after:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim rng As Range
    Set rng = Range("MITCH")
    If Target.Address = rng.MergeArea.Address Then 'check if what's selected matches the named range entirely
        MsgBox ("Hello World")
    End If
End Sub
```

As this checks whether the cells you have selected perfectly map onto the named area - specifically the *MergeArea* of the named range.

Matching with `Intersect` just checks if the selection *contains* the named Range

Matching by TL cell means *any selection* with the same TL as the named Range will also return a positive. E.g, if `[B2:D3]` is your merged named range, then matching by `[B2]` will return positive if `[B2:D3]` is selected (as expected), but also when `[B2:XX100]` is selected

This code only returns positive when the areas are identical, i.e. only the merged cell is selected.

Comment: Thank you Greedo- this is awesome!

Answer (score 0):

If you have named the range you could use the code below

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim tName As String
    On Error Resume Next
    tName = Target.Name.Name
    On Error GoTo 0
    If Len(tName) > 0 Then
        If tName = "MITCH" Then
            MsgBox ("Hello World")
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```